# Do any newer production aircraft use venturis as a backup vacuum source?

Tags: aircraft-design, general-aviation, aircraft-systems

I began my flight training in a Cessna 120 with 2 venturis as the source of vacuum for my DG and TC. They worked well in flight.

Are there any aircraft with deployed/deployable venturis out there? Other than my 1946 vintage C-120 which is also my birth year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I know. Even Vacuum pump systems are quickly becoming a thing of the past. [Electric AI's are available](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/inpages/gh02e-3.php?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1q3VBRCFARIsAPHJXrHUhubpPR0Htz3PlfSKx85wpd4_REpAfYteB0MmWCrhHdP9RepDyS0aArSWEALw_wcB) and I have seen plenty in use. However with [glass cockpits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garmin_G1000) making their way into general aviation [AHARS units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_and_heading_reference_system) are becoming more and more common place over traditional vacuum systems. There are even some [small drop in units intended to replace traditional vacuum systems like DG's and Attitude Indicators](https://www.gulfcoastavionics.com/products/4202-g5-efis-certified.aspx). Venturi vacuums, while simple have down sides like potential icing risks and needing sufficient airflow to function.

Comment: A complete electrical failure in a non battery powered backup AI would still require a vacuum source.  Although I must admit the venturi became less visible on aircraft as I advanced through many different models through the years, until the complete absence in 'modern' IFR capable aircraft.

Comment: @mikebrass that is incorrect, to be [certified as a backup electric AI](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2023.1311-1C.pdf) the unit must have a second independent power supply not driven by the main system typically this is an internal backup battery but can be fed off a second electrical system in a twin engine scenario.